# How do you solve this? I have been trying to solve this since a long time

Tags: limits, continuity

if $2f(\sin x)+(2^1/2), f(\cos x)= \tan x$ then Limit $(1-x)^{1/2}$.
$f(x**)$ where $x>0$ and **$x$ tends to $1$**

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $\arcsin y=x,y=\sin x$ and $-\dfrac\pi2\le y\le\dfrac\pi2$

$\cos x=\sqrt{1-y^2} $

$$2f(y)+\sqrt2f(\sqrt{1-y^2})=\dfrac y{\sqrt{1-y^2}}$$

Set $y=z$

$$2f(z)+\sqrt2f(\sqrt{1-z^2})=\dfrac z{\sqrt{1-z^2}}\ \ \ \  (1)$$

Set $\sqrt{1-y^2}=z$

$$2f(\sqrt{1-z^2})+\sqrt2f(z)=\dfrac{\sqrt{1-z^2}}z\ \ \ \  (2)$$

Solve $(1),(2)$ for $f(z)$

Comment: ok so after finding f(z) and f(x) how will you use their values in the second part of the question that is: find the  Limit (1-x)^1/2.f(x) where x tends to 1

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$2f(\sin x)+\sqrt2f(\cos x)=\tan x\ \ \ \ (1)$$

Replace $x$ with $\dfrac\pi2-x$

$$2f(\cos x)+\sqrt2f(\sin x)=\cot x\ \ \ \ (2)$$

Solve $(1),(2)$ for $f(\sin x)$